# Create pyramid numbers using for loop

Tags: swift

I am trying to create pyramid with numbers:

eg.

for max elements (how many times for loop will goes): 8, 12 or 24 I would like to get order :

```
8 - 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 9, 6, 3
12 - 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2
24 - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

This example is acording to displaying time with AM / PM system without using `Date` objects.

```
let maxElements = 8

for i in 0...maxElements {
    print(i * 24 / maxElements)
}
```

This simple for loop will display a time for a 24h type. I am missing an ideas how could I prove it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. Where is a pyramid, why does the first increment by 3, the second by 2 and the last by 1?

Comment: Could you make it more clear? btw, are you trying to solve a homework :)

Comment: And if so, don't you have a mistake in your 8 item array? (Hint, you only listed 7 elements.)

Comment: @dfd Yes, forgot one number. Thank you

Comment: @AhmadF Nope, It is for self education. Trying to avoid a lot of conditions with formating labels with text. Like I've mentioned I would like to display a time. It would depends of numbers which I'll give. The number of labeles / rows depends of the "maxElements". The example which I've created giving me the Time with 24h style. from 0:00 till 23:59. I'd like to convert it into 12h style - 12AM - 12PM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
func generateNumbers(maxElements: Int) {
    let step = 24 / maxElements
    var generatedArray = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<maxElements {

        if i < maxElements / 2 {
            generatedArray.append(i * step)

        } else {
            generatedArray.append(24 - i * step)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also replace the `for` loop by using `map(_:)` to make the code more compact like this:

```
_ = (0..<maxElements).enumerated().map({ (index, element) in
    index < maxElements / 2 ? generatedArray.append(index * step) : generatedArray.append(24 - index * step)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've solved my problem just before you've posted.

Comment: I updated my answer to make the code more compact. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem.

```
let maxElements = 8
var tmp = 0

for i in 0...maxElements {
    var result = i * 24 / maxElements

    if i >= maxElements / 2 {
        result = result - tmp * (24 / maxElements * 2)
        tmp += 1
    }

    print(result)
}
```